# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

Tags: android

I am using com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView in order to render 360 degree photo in android application. I am following the instruction in this example:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vr_view_app_101/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2016#0
Every Time I try to deploy my application using emulator I have this error:
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ARM emulator instead of an Intel based emulator (HAXM) or the other way round. This error usually means the architecture doesn't match.